# Powershell Send-MailMessage InlineAttachments parameter cannot be found

Tags: powershell, sendmail, optional-parameters

I don't know why this parameter can't be found, but for some reason when using the example from David Wyatt on the [Technet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-MailMessage-3a920a6d) Powershell is kicking back the error:

> Send-MailMessage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'InlineAttachments'.

I'm not using an old Powershell version or server, it is on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with PS versions of:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17090
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: We would need to visually see the line where you call `Send-MailMessage` and possible any variable assignments before that, to help you effectively.  Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38270914/edit) and provide this to us when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download and install the Send-MailMessage cmdlet from the TechNet link you provided. The native version of Send-MailMessage does not have the InlineAttachments parameter.